# How to insert an already existing dom element instead of returning html string

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, helper

Handlebars guide has an example of how to implement helper methods. But how can I render an already existing element instead of getting outerHTML of this element and return it as a string. I need this because of my Ember views setting events on elements and when I getting outerHTML it generates new dom elements, and events of views does not fire UP.

Ok I have backbone View that getting Handlebars precompiled template

```
SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialise: function(){
    this.render();
  },

  render: function(){
    html = HandlebarsTemplates.some_template();
    this.el.innerHtml = html;
  },

  raiseAlert: function(){
    alert('Some message');
  },

  events: {
    'click': 'raiseAlert'
  }
})
```

And I have Handlebars helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper 'show', function(){
  var view = new SomeView({});
  var result = view.el.outerHTML;
  new Handlebars.SafeString(result)
}
```

So I want to not use outerHtml but insert view.el instead.

Comment: Could you please clarify xour question? What is it exactly you want and how is this related to backbone.js?

Comment: It is *very* unclear to me what you are trying to achieve with your "show" helper method. However, I think it would start you down the right path to try and move this logic into the "SomeView" Backbone view.